# binding is not defined while using Ghost.py

Tags: python, pip, ghost.py

I am writing a script and having trouble even getting a basic one to work. Ghost seems to not be importing properly. I keep getting the following error:

```
>>>from ghost import Ghost
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ghost/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .ghost import Ghost, Error, TimeoutError
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ghost/ghost.py", line 23, in <module>
    if binding is None:
NameError: name 'binding' is not defined
```

Nothing special in the code:

```
 from ghost import Ghost
 ghost = Ghost()
```

I have PySide and PyQt both installed and I install Ghost by doing: sudo pip install ghost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the Ghost.py source code](https://github.com/jeanphix/Ghost.py/blob/5660e1db64376dfca5b6521fdf361422d7db8f0f/ghost/ghost.py#L23):

```
...
bindings = ["PySide", "PyQt4"]

for name in bindings:
    try:
        binding = __import__(name)
        break
    except ImportError:
        continue


if binding is None:
    raise Exception("Ghost.py requires PySide or PyQt4")
...
```

`binding` is defined when at least one of PySide or PyQt4 is installed. Check you PySide, PyQt4(not PyQt5) installation using following `import` statement:

```
import PySide

import PyQt4
```

BTW, causing `NameError` instead of Exception with the message `"Ghost.py requires PySide or PyQt4"` is a bug. So [I commented this](https://github.com/jeanphix/Ghost.py/commit/bc0688274b7aeb6aa077927a09ce4ce75f1c3ede#commitcomment-4951119).

Comment: So both importing PySide and PyQt4 did not work. I installed them using homebrew (eg. brew install pyqt). It is there another way I should have installed them for it to work?

Comment: @Zaheer, I don't know about *homebrew*. IMHO, *homebrew* installed `PyQt` to python instance A, while *pip* installed Ghost.py to instance B.